# Why do we need to compact and repair the database after currentdb.tabledefs.append

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I was trying to create a linked table in Access using DSN less connection with VBA. I found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/892490/how-to-create-a-dsn-less-connection-to-sql-server-for-linked-tables-in) really helpful link online. Here is the code from the link:

```
'//Name     :   AttachDSNLessTable
'//Purpose  :   Create a linked table to SQL Server without using a DSN
'//Parameters
'//     stLocalTableName: Name of the table that you are creating in the current database
'//     stRemoteTableName: Name of the table that you are linking to on the SQL Server database
'//     stServer: Name of the SQL Server that you are linking to
'//     stDatabase: Name of the SQL Server database that you are linking to
'//     stUsername: Name of the SQL Server user who can connect to SQL Server, leave blank to use a Trusted Connection
'//     stPassword: SQL Server user password
Function AttachDSNLessTable(stLocalTableName As String, stRemoteTableName As String, stServer As String, stDatabase As String, Optional stUsername As String, Optional stPassword As String)
    On Error GoTo AttachDSNLessTable_Err
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim stConnect As String

    For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If td.Name = stLocalTableName Then
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stLocalTableName
        End If
    Next

    If Len(stUsername) = 0 Then
        '//Use trusted authentication if stUsername is not supplied.
        stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    Else
        '//WARNING: This will save the username and the password with the linked table information.
        stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";UID=" & stUsername & ";PWD=" & stPassword
    End If
    Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, stConnect)
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
    AttachDSNLessTable = True
    Exit Function

AttachDSNLessTable_Err:

    AttachDSNLessTable = False
    MsgBox "AttachDSNLessTable encountered an unexpected error: " & Err.Description

End Function
```

As you can see each tabledef is added at the end using

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
```

The code passed through for me without any errors. But the tables did not appear in my Access. Only when I did compact and repair database, the tables appeared. I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After appending object to collection you have to refresh the collection: `CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh`.

And to see chenges in database window : `Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow`

> The RefreshDatabaseWindow method updates the Database window (Database
>   window: In Access 2003 and earlier, the window that appears when a
>   database or project is opened. It displays shortcuts for creating new
>   database objects and opening existing objects. In later versions, it
>   is replaced by the Navigation Pane.) after a database object (database
>   objects: An Access database contains objects such as tables, queries,
>   forms, reports, pages, macros, and modules. An Access project contains
>   objects such as forms, reports, pages, macros, and modules.) has been
>   created, deleted, or renamed.

Comment: Certainly right. The reference code by Microsoft doesn't include this, because if you want to attach multiple tables, you generally want to run these two statements only once (after appending all tables).

Comment: Makes sense. I just added Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow and it worked. Didn't have to use CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh.

Comment: @namko `CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh` refresh only one collection `TableDefs`, and not database window. While `RefreshDatabaseWindow` refresh seven collections *and* repaints database window.